# Android BluetoothAdapter Disable function not working on Device 2.3.6

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm not able to disable Bluetooth in my app on devices which have lower android version(checking on 2.3.6) at 4.0 + version its working fine. here is my simple code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    findViewById(R.id.helloTxt).setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {       
    if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {            
        mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
    }
}
}
```

also given necessary permission in manifest:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
```

and logcat result on the device generated by aLogCat app.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(28167): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(28167): java.lang.SecurityException: Calling uid 10097 gave packageandroid which is owned by uid 1000
E/AndroidRuntime(28167):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1322)
E/AndroidRuntime(28167):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
E/AndroidRuntime(28167):    at android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy.disable(IBluetooth.java:632)
E/AndroidRuntime(28167):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.disable(BluetoothAdapter.java:563)
E/AndroidRuntime(28167):    at com.example.bluetoothtest.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:25)
E/AndroidRuntime(28167):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
E/AndroidRuntime(28167):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
E/AndroidRuntime(28167):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(28167):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(28167):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime(28167):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
E/AndroidRuntime(28167):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(28167):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(28167):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
E/AndroidRuntime(28167):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
E/AndroidRuntime(28167):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

its crashes app in android 2.3.6 version devices. please help !!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: whats the crash, report logcat

Comment: @Siddharth thanks for response, i have added the logcat details. please help.

Comment: I've received a report just like this involving BluetoothAdapter.disable(). All users are running Android 4.x so it's not due to an older version. I suspect it may be a user running PrivacyGuard (?) and denying certain permissions to the app, in this case Bluetooth. Would like to see a definitive response.

Answer (score 0):

To get a BluetoothAdapter representing the local Bluetooth adapter, when running on JELLY_BEAN_MR1 and below, call the static getDefaultAdapter() method; when running on JELLY_BEAN_MR2 and higher, retrieve it through getSystemService(String) with BLUETOOTH_SERVICE.